# Impossible to add the product to the cart. Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When i try to add cart this happen . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMCpM.png)after i disabled the Special block and enabled the top seller this happen. When i try to revert, the problem still the same. Thanks

Comment: Do you have some 3rd party module that overrides `Cart` class ? Some gift/souvenire box module, maybe.

Comment: @PH_Laza it seems a modification done directly in the code. $pasalubongbox is not a standard cart property.

Comment: Btw, I think that if you disable errors it will work correctly

Comment: @joseantgv, When i try to disable  the error the pop up or the add to cart. the modal is not showing.

Comment: @NilJimenezJr. and the product is added to the cart?

Answer (score 0):

This error must be generated through some third party module on your store. In order to identify the module you need to observe the ajax request (Sent on 'Add to Cart' click), after enabling error debugging.

FYI, to enable error debugging you can follow the steps below.

- open file: config/defines.inc.php (using FTP or hosting control panel)
- change false-->true:

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);